# Gson deserialisation returns null

Tags: json, gson

I have a problem on converting JSON string to object in Android. Here are the JSON structure and Java classes:

JSON:

```
{
"code":"SUCCEED",
"message":"",
"result":{
    "ccahUserId": 111,
    "ccahUserName":"your_name",
    "userFirstName":"your_first_name",
    "userLastName":"your_last_name",

    //others
}
```

Java classes:

```
public class Result<T>{
   public String code;
   public String message;
   public T result;   
}

public class DeviceSetting 
{
    public long ccahUserId;
    public String ccahUserName;
    public String userFirstName;
    public String userLastName;
    //other members

}
```

Activity:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Result<DeviceSetting> setting = gson.fromJson(result, Result<DeviceSetting>.class);
```

When I deserialise the JSON string, code and message field were good but result field is null.
I am not familiar with Gson yet, so please help how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Likely the `result` field is null because it relies on the type parameter for `Result`.

From the [GSON documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) for `Gson.fromJson(JsonElement, Class<T>)` (bolding is mine):

> This method deserializes the Json read from the specified parse tree
>   into an object of the specified type. ***It is not suitable to use if the
>   specified class is a generic type*** since it will not have the generic
>   type information because of the Type Erasure feature of Java. Therefore, this method should not be used if the desired type is a generic type. Note that this method works fine if the any of the fields of the specified object are generics, just the object itself should not be a generic type. For the cases when the object is of generic type, invoke `fromJson(JsonElement, Type)`.

Comment: Thanks for the good point and kind answer! You saved my time.

Comment: @user1090973: If this answers your question, please be sure to tick the check mark to select this as the answer.